Vertex AI Vector Search support text2vector?
I'm currently exploring Vertex AI Vector Search and I'm particularly interested in its capabilities regarding text to vector conversion (text2vector). I have a couple of questions:
1.Does Vertex AI Vector Search natively support converting text to vectors?
2.If it doesn't, are there any No Code solutions or tools that integrate well with Vertex AI for text2vector conversion?
Any insights, resources, or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
I have been exploring the Vertex AI documentation and experimenting with its vector search capabilities. I expected to find built-in support for text to vector conversion (text2vector), but I haven't found clear information on this. I also tried searching for No Code solutions that integrate with Vertex AI for this purpose but couldn't find concrete examples or recommendations. Any help or guidance would be appreciated.
